# Can you glBlitFramebuffer between different levels of the same texture?

Tags: opengl-es, framebuffer, mipmaps

Let's say I have a texture that I need to mipmap but I want the mipmapping done hardware accelerated. I decided the best route to take would be something like this:

```
    int read = glGenFramebuffers();
    int draw = glGenFramebuffers();
    int wh = 256;
    int glObject = glGenTextures();
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, glObject);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, wh, wh, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

    for(int i = 0; i < mipLevels; ++i) {
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, read);
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, glObject, i);
            
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, i + 1, GL_RGBA8, wh / 2, wh / 2, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (ByeBuffer)null);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, draw);
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, glObject, i + 1);
            
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, read);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, draw);
        glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, wh, wh, 0, 0, wh / 2, wh / 2,  GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_LINEAR);
            
        wh /= 2;
    }
```

Both framebuffers return INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT in this block of code when glCheckFramebufferStatus is called. What am I doing wrong? Am I allocating the blank mipmap levels correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: I was using `glTexImage2D` to allocate blank mip levels when I should have used `glTexStorage2D` to allocate the blank levels under these circumstances. Here is a link to the manual page for `glTexStorage2D` for more details: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexStorage2D.xhtml